# Access page variable from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to access public variables declared in the code behind from a JavaScript function, e.g.

```
var user = <%=User%>;
```

Where User is declared in the code behind as:

```
public string User = "";
```

And then set in the `page_load` event.

Comment: yes it is, if this code is contained in you asp.net page not in separate js file. and kindly add quotes in case of strings var user = '<%=User%>';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var userID = '<%= UserID %>';
     var courseID = '<%= CourseID %>';

     .... more stuff....
 </script>
```

Then set the values on Page_Load (or in the Page_Load for the master page).

```
 public void Page_Load( object source, EventArgs e )
  {

        UserID = Session["userID"];
        CourseID = Session["courseID"];
        ...
  }
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you! I'd missed the single quotes.